# Is it possible to apply a live background in scrollable view in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 4 screens in my application that is scrollable. When I try to apply a live background/short mp4 it doesn't show. I tried it on the other screens that I did not apply the scrollable view and it works. I am wondering whether it is not possible or maybe my code is wrong.

I just want to ask if it's possible or not. I can provide the source codes if needed. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply an mp4 as background for `ScrollView` because mp4 has a specific height and width and you can't scroll it. But if you want to add an mp4 in the background what you can do is, you can set the height and width of the mp4 as `match parent` and you can apply `ScrollView` on top of that as background transparent. I hope it will work.